# Converting a DateTime to Utc given a timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

I don't want to keep having to change the config everytime there is a daylight savings change. This is what I am currently doing which doesn't work as it uses "Standard" time.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time")
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZone); // This doesn't take into account that it's daylight savings...
```

Is there a one size fits all solution. So I can give it a datetime and a location like "US east coast" and it give me the time in Utc?

Comment: What is the question? Can you explain more detailed your problem? What does mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: Well it's currently 1 hour off due to daylight savings.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - are you sure `dateTime` is being set correctly?

Comment: Input time of 7.50am should result in 11.50am, but it is resulting in 12.50pm.

Comment: but **current** (because DST was enabled at 10 March) offset for `US Eastern Standard Time` is `-5`. Are you sure that input date in the `US Eastern Standard Time` timezone?

Comment: I made a mistake. I was after "Eastern Standard Time"

Answer (score 5):

I've done it before by storing the timezone id in the database using a mapping table. i.e. A table containing the results of `TimeZone.GetSystemTimeZones()`

You don't actually need to use TimeZoneInfo.`FindSystemTimeZoneById()` though: you can do the conversion using one of the overloads of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()`. This method has some overloads which take `DateTime` values, and some that take `DateTimeOffset` values (which are preferable as they specify an unambiguous point in time).

e.g.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, "New Zealand Standard Time", "UTC")
```

The real benefit of using the system time zone id rather than an offset stored in the database is that daylight savings time is automatically handled for you by `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`.

This msdn also might prove helpful to you>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382058.aspx

Comment: nput time of 7.50am should result in 11.50am, but it is resulting in 12.50pm.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Pass DateTime and TimeZone of the Location and Convert the provided DateTime to UTC

Check this [Example Here](https://rextester.com/ING80333)

```
       string DisplayName = "custom standard name here";//custom Standard Name to display eg: Kathmandu
       string StandardName = "custom standard name here"; // custom Standard Name eg: Asia/Kathamandu, Nepal
       string YourDate="27-03-2019 20:24:56"; // this DateTime doesn't contain any timeZone
       TimeSpan Offset = new TimeSpan(+5, 30, 00);// your TimeZone offset eg: timeZone of Nepal is +5:45
       TimeZoneInfo TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(StandardName, Offset, DisplayName, StandardName);
       var RawDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(YourDate), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);// I all it RawDateTime Since it doesn't contain any TimeSpan
       DateTime UTCDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(RawDateTime, TimeZone);
       Console.WriteLine(UTCDateTime);
```